# Efficient code for fetching all duplicate records on large datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to assign scores of zero to any record having duplicates and a score of 1 to all unique records. I have a set of data like this:
Table 1-

| No. | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | Aachen |
| 5 | Berlin |
| 6 | Berlin |
| 7 | Berlin |
| 8 | Bochum |
| 9 | Bochum |
| 10 | Bristol |
| 11 | Liverpool |
| 12 | Liverpool |

So, the expected result will be:
Table 2 -

| No. | City | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 0 |
| 2 | null | 0 |
| 3 | null | 0 |
| 4 | Aachen | 1 |
| 5 | Berlin | 0 |
| 6 | Berlin | 0 |
| 7 | Berlin | 0 |
| 8 | Bochum | 0 |
| 9 | Bochum | 0 |
| 10 | Bristol | 1 |
| 11 | Liverpool | 0 |
| 12 | Liverpool | 0 |

```
select city,
case  when [City] in ( select [City] from [Table1] group by [City] having count([City]) = 1) then 1 else 0 end as [Score]
   from Table1
```

This code works well on datasets smaller than 100k rows but if it deals with larger datasets it is too slow and the execution time runs out sometimes. It is important to recognize null values as duplicates as well. Can anyone please suggest a more efficient solution than this?

Comment: Obligatory note: SQL Server 2008 is long unsupported. It is well past time you sorted your upgrade path by now.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 went out of support a *very long* time ago. Windowing functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` weren't available back then.

Comment: `It is important to recognize null values as duplicates as well.` In SQL, `NULL` isn't a value, it means there's no value at all. Perhaps it has no meaning, perhaps it wasn't stored yet. Treating NULLs as duplicate, while possible, is a bit suspicious

Comment: for my use case, nulls need to be treated as duplicates.

Comment: Why do you keep removing the tag [[tag:sql-server]]? You've tagged [[tag:tsql]] which normally implies SQL Server (as that's the dialect SQL Server uses). Are you, therefore, actually using Sybase..? Sybase is the only other RDBMS to use T-SQL. What RDBMS are you *really* using if not SQL Server (and why did you tag SQL Server 2008 initially if you aren't using SQL Server)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `ROW_NUMBER` was available in SQL Server 2008 (R2). It was things like `SUM` and `COUNT` that you couldn't window. Pretty sure `ROW_NUMBER` was available in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: As per my understanding, it is not mentioned that on which version of SQL server the code is being run. So ROW_NUMBER() function can be used. In order to recognize NULLs as duplicate better we perform a case statement for all the NULL as 'A' and then apply ROW_NUMBER() and while displaying the output we revert the case statement.

Comment: @Larnu please don't assume tags, especially with databases. Instead, ask OP to add the right tags. Nafisa, which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Comment: @Bohemian it's not an assumption; the OP tagged [[tag:sql-server-2008]] initially, and **still** has [[tag:tsql]] tagged... T-SQL is the dialect SQL Server uses, and SQL Server 2008 is a version of SQL Server. Your statement is like saying "Don't assume Visual Studio 2022 is Visual Studio". Of course it is... *" Instead, ask OP to add the right tags. "* you mean like [I already did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72129731/efficient-code-for-fetching-all-duplicate-records-on-large-datasets#comment127445912_72129731)? *"What RDBMS are you really using if not SQL Server"*

Comment: @larnu let OP clarify and if that doesn't happen you may vote to close for insufficient detail.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact there is no assumption, @Bohemian; your comment is incorrect. The OP may be misinforming us, but there were no assumptions on my part. It is a *fact* that they stated they are using SQL Server (2008). I have, therefore, removed the [[tag:tsql]] to further help others not make  safe and informed conclusions on the OP's own (potentially incorrect) statements.

Comment: @NafisaAfsanaTaskia do you always want all rows? ie No `where` clause?

Comment: yes, i need all records actually

Answer (score 2):

Below is the solution that I have implemented.
Reason for converting the NULLs to some character is because NULLs will be eliminated if we apply a count function

```
create table temp
(id int,
city varchar(200))

insert into temp
values
(1,null),
(2,null),
(3,null),
(4,'Aachen'),
(5,'Berlin'),
(6,'Berlin'),
(7,'Berlin'),
(8,'Bochum'),
(9,'Bochum'),
(10,'Bristol'),
(11,'Liverpool'),
(12,'Liverpool')

;with cte as (
select id, case when city is null then 'A' else city end as city from temp)

select id, case when city ='A' then NULL else city end as city, 
case when count(city) over (partition by city order by city )>1 then 0 else 1 end as score
from cte
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.  Also, rather than put the entire demo in your answer, link to an online demo using http://sqlfiddle.com, https://www.db-fiddle.com or https://dbfiddle.uk etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be faster, depends on how the query builder works for Sql Server 2008. But it feels faster for me to structure the query like this :)

```
select [City],
coalesce(score, 0) as score
from [Table1] t
left join
(select [City], 1 as score from [Table1]
group by [City] having count([City]) = 1
) x on x.[City] = t.[City]
```